# How to set kafka config to print log in console when running kafka source code in idea

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm running the kafka source code of 3.1 branch  in ubuntu22.04

But, there is no output logs in the console when running kafka source code in idea：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCY9B.png)

And this is my run config：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHagr.png)

Below is my server.properties

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# see kafka.server.KafkaConfig for additional details and defaults

############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=0

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from 
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
#listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092

# Hostname and port the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set, 
# it uses the value for "listeners" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value
# returned from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
#advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092

# Maps listener names to security protocols, the default is for them to be the same. See the config documentation for more details
#listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL

# The number of threads that the server uses for receiving requests from the network and sending responses to the network
num.network.threads=3

# The number of threads that the server uses for processing requests, which may include disk I/O
num.io.threads=8

# The send buffer (SO_SNDBUF) used by the socket server
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

# The receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) used by the socket server
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

# The maximum size of a request that the socket server will accept (protection against OOM)
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600


############################# Log Basics #############################

# A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs

# The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater
# parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across
# the brokers.
num.partitions=1

# The number of threads per data directory to be used for log recovery at startup and flushing at shutdown.
# This value is recommended to be increased for installations with data dirs located in RAID array.
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################
# The replication factor for the group metadata internal topics "__consumer_offsets" and "__transaction_state"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended to ensure availability such as 3.
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1

############################# Log Flush Policy #############################

# Messages are immediately written to the filesystem but by default we only fsync() to sync
# the OS cache lazily. The following configurations control the flush of data to disk.
# There are a few important trade-offs here:
#    1. Durability: Unflushed data may be lost if you are not using replication.
#    2. Latency: Very large flush intervals may lead to latency spikes when the flush does occur as there will be a lot of data to flush.
#    3. Throughput: The flush is generally the most expensive operation, and a small flush interval may lead to excessive seeks.
# The settings below allow one to configure the flush policy to flush data after a period of time or
# every N messages (or both). This can be done globally and overridden on a per-topic basis.

# The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk
#log.flush.interval.messages=10000

# The maximum amount of time a message can sit in a log before we force a flush
#log.flush.interval.ms=1000

############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

# The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
# be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
# A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
# from the end of the log.

# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion due to age
log.retention.hours=168

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log unless the remaining
# segments drop below log.retention.bytes. Functions independently of log.retention.hours.
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824

# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
log.segment.bytes=1073741824

# The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according
# to the retention policies
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

############################# Zookeeper #############################

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
# root directory for all kafka znodes.
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000


############################# Group Coordinator Settings #############################

# The following configuration specifies the time, in milliseconds, that the GroupCoordinator will delay the initial consumer rebalance.
# The rebalance will be further delayed by the value of group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms as new members join the group, up to a maximum of max.poll.interval.ms.
# The default value for this is 3 seconds.
# We override this to 0 here as it makes for a better out-of-the-box experience for development and testing.
# However, in production environments the default value of 3 seconds is more suitable as this will help to avoid unnecessary, and potentially expensive, rebalances during application startup.
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

Below is my config/log4j.properties, there is a same log4j.properties in core/src/main/resources

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# Unspecified loggers and loggers with additivity=true output to server.log and stdout
# Note that INFO only applies to unspecified loggers, the log level of the child logger is used otherwise
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, kafkaAppender

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.kafkaAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.File=/tmp/kafka-logs/server.log
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.File=/tmp/kafka-logs/state-change.log
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.requestAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.requestAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.requestAppender.File=/tmp/kafka-logs/kafka-request.log
log4j.appender.requestAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.requestAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.cleanerAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.File=/tmp/kafka-logs/log-cleaner.log
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.controllerAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.File=/tmp/kafka-logs/controller.log
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.authorizerAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.File=/tmp/kafka-logs/kafka-authorizer.log
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

# Change the line below to adjust ZK client logging
log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=INFO

# Change the two lines below to adjust the general broker logging level (output to server.log and stdout)
log4j.logger.kafka=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka=INFO

# Change to DEBUG or TRACE to enable request logging
log4j.logger.kafka.request.logger=WARN, requestAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.request.logger=false

# Uncomment the lines below and change log4j.logger.kafka.network.RequestChannel$ to TRACE for additional output
# related to the handling of requests
#log4j.logger.kafka.network.Processor=TRACE, requestAppender
#log4j.logger.kafka.server.KafkaApis=TRACE, requestAppender
#log4j.additivity.kafka.server.KafkaApis=false
log4j.logger.kafka.network.RequestChannel$=WARN, requestAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.network.RequestChannel$=false

log4j.logger.kafka.controller=TRACE, controllerAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.controller=false

log4j.logger.kafka.log.LogCleaner=INFO, cleanerAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.log.LogCleaner=false

log4j.logger.state.change.logger=INFO, stateChangeAppender
log4j.additivity.state.change.logger=false

# Access denials are logged at INFO level, change to DEBUG to also log allowed accesses
log4j.logger.kafka.authorizer.logger=INFO, authorizerAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.authorizer.logger=false
```

I'm expecting there are much output in the console when running kafka source code.

Comment: What class are you running? KafkaServer?

Comment: You could instead create a shell run config that starts `kafka-server-start.sh`...this script is responsible for setting up log4j and other classpath items

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer , I just run the script in a shell, but it still show noting except the output at the being


```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/morty/project/kafka/core/build/dependant-libs-2.13.6/slf4j-nop-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

```

Comment: Sorry, I am not expressing accurately, I want to debug the source code and see the log  in idea  console not just running the source code

Comment: Nothing prevents you from debugging or seeing logs when using the shell script

Comment: If you're getting sl4j errors, you'll need to manually configure log4j on your own using system properties

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thank you, I run the code in my mac idea with the same configurations, and it show the log.

Comment: I didn't look at your run config image before, but it works now? What did you change?

Comment: I still run the kafka.scala, and the config is with no change --https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHagr.png, then I change the value of log4j.appender.{}.file to my userhome, it still doesn't works now, then I clone the code one time again, ant keep same configure, it works now in trunk branch

Comment: I found it, after I use kafkaManager whoes name is cmak now, it will print log, but when I use spring-kafka client, only the thread stop at a breakpoint, then it will print log....